# to display custom members in view for event mgmt task

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

```
        $scope.eMgmt.push({
            name:$scope.eventname,
            desc:$scope.eventDesc,
            strDate:$scope.dt,
            strTime:$scope.mytime,
            endDate:$scope.dt1,
            endTime:$scope.mytime1,
            eType:$scope.radioModel,
            eventMembers1:$scope.evtMem,

        })
            **strong text**
```

how to add evtMem[] having objects to eMgmt array

Comment: What are you trying to do? Merge two arrays into one?

Comment: what `$scope.evtMem` contains?

Comment: $scope.evtMem contains selected members thru typeahead